# Security Scanner finds XSS False Positives / JSENCODE incompatible with Boolean fields?

Tags: visualforce, isv, security-review, cross-domain

Before I submit my app for Security Review I checked it with the free scanner.
It marked the following line of JS-code in a Visualforce as Critical XSS vulnerability:

```
<script>var trueOrFalse = '{!MyObject__c.chk_CheckboxField__c}';</script>
```

As far as I know I cannot go into security review with such findings, although this is a False Positive as the report mentions.
How can I cure this efficiently?

```
<script>var trueOrFalse = '{!JSENCODE(MyObject__c.chk_CheckboxField__c)}';</script>
```

does not work as JSENCODE expects text and not boolean.

```
<script>var trueOrFalse = '{!JSENCODE(TEXT(MyObject__c.chk_CheckboxField__c))}';</script>
```

also doesn't work, as TEXT() not accepts Boolean values.

What should I do?

Comment: You can include a document describing your false positives, and explaining why you did it this way.

Comment: @RobertSösemann Have you figured out the best approach to deal with the same? I am facing the same challenge.

Answer (score 8):

You do not need to rewrite the code to eliminate scanner false positives -- there will always be false positives.

However, if you want to rewrite the code, then you can replace a boolean with a text literal and then cast to a Bool.

```
<script>
var foo = Boolean('{!JSENCODE(IF(MyObject__c.chk_CheckboxField__c,"true", "false"))}'); //absurd way to quiet scanner
</script>
```

As an aside, in the next iteration of the rules, this false positive should be taken care of.

Comment: Did anyone come up with a better - less hacky - solution since 2014? It obscures my code in so many places that I still didn't use it.

Comment: Boolean('false') and Boolean('true') both will return true because both are booleans.

Comment: Both Boolean('false') and Boolean('true') will be true so following check solved my problem : '{!JSENCODE(IF(MyObject__c.chk_CheckboxField__c,"true", "false"))}' === 'true'